# Access multiple columns in a 3D numpy array without looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a large 3D array `A` with shape `(N, M, L)`.

I have a list of coordinates of columns I want to access stored in a 2D array `B`:

```
[[i1 j1]
 [i2 j2]
 [i3 j3]
 ....   ]
```

I have something that works OK but involves looping over `B` and accessing `A` multiple times. Is there a way to avoid this using slicing or another method?

My code so far:

```
data_out = []
for p in B:
    i, j = p
    col = A[:, i, j]
    data_out.append(col)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fancy indexing:

```
A[(slice(None), *B.T)].T
```

The explicit parentheses are necessary to use star expansion, which means that you have to write out `:` explicitly as `slice(None)`. You can also do

```
A[:, B[:, 0], B[:, 1]].T
```

Comment: @Divakar. Fixed. I forgot that B was being split into 1D and relied on its shape :)